# SID revisions numbers

Tags: sid-star, departure-sid

I have noticed most instrument departures have a number after them. TRUKN2 GAP7 CITY3 for example at KSFO. Do the numbers represent a revision of say TRUNK1 GAP6 CITY3 for maybe a change in and altitude due to construction of a building, or FAA SID Departure criteria? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. The number indicates a *version* of the procedure, and runs from `1` to `9` before cycling back to `1`. The changes may be due to newly-surveyed obstructions, or changes in ATC procedures to allow for more efficient traffic flow, or the decommissioning of conventional NAVAIDs (VORs) which used to be part of a procedure.

The FAA publishes documents highlighting the changes between successive versions of procedures, for example [this one shows the changes between the FROGZ TWO and FROGZ THREE arrivals.](https://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/2209/compare_pdf/00257frogz_cmp.pdf) These and other terminal procedures can be accessed at [the Terminal Procedures site.](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dtpp/) Third parties like SkyVector also show these documents.

Comment: Wonderful answer and explanation ! Thank you so much for you help and sharing your knowledge!